# Calculus Problem from Courant's Calculus textbook

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, derivatives

Link to the question:

> Let the function $f(\xi)$ be continuous for all values of $\xi$, and
> let $F(x)$ be defined by the equation \begin{align}
>   F(x)=\frac{1}{2\delta}\int_{-\delta}^\delta f(x+t)\,dt, \end{align} where
> $\delta$ is an arbitrary positive number Prove that:
>
> 1. the function $F(x)$ possesses a continuous derivative for all values of $x$;
> 2. in any fixed interval $a\leq x\leq b$ we can make $|F(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$, where $\epsilon$ is an arbitrary pre-assigned
>    positive number, by choosing $\delta$ small enough.

Here is my solution to the problem:

> 1. 
>
> \begin{align} F(x)&=\frac{1}{2\delta}\int_{-\delta}^\delta f(x+t)\,dt \\ &=\frac{1}{2\delta}\int_{x-\delta}^{x+\delta} f(t)\,dt
>  \\ &=\frac{1}{2\delta}\left\{\int_{c}^{x+\delta}
>  f(t)-\int_{c}^{x-\delta}f(t)\,dt\right\} \\
>  &=\frac{1}{2\delta}\left\{\int_{c-\delta}^{x}
>  f(t+\delta)-\int_{c+\delta}^{x}f(t-\delta)\,dt\right\}\,. \end{align}
> $F'(x)=\frac{1}{2\delta}\left\{f(x+\delta)-f(x-\delta)\right\}$ by the
> fundamental theorem.
>
> Since $f(x)$ is continuous everywhere, $F(x)$ will also be continuous
> everywhere.
>
> 2.
> \begin{align} |F(x)-f(x)|&=\left|\frac{1}{2\delta}\int_{-\delta}^{\delta}f(x+t)\,dt-f(x)\right|
>  \\
>  &=\left|\frac{1}{2\delta}\int_{x-\delta}^{x+\delta}f(t)\,dt-f(x)\right| \\ &=\left|\frac{1}{2\delta}2\delta f(\xi)-f(x)\right|\,,\text{ where
>  $\xi\in(x-\delta,x+\delta)$} \\ &=|f(\xi)-f(x)|\,. \end{align}
> From the continuity of $f$, we know that for all $\epsilon>0,
> > \exists\delta>0$ s.t. $|x-x_1|<\delta$ implies
> $|f(x)-f(x_1)|<\epsilon$,.
>
> Since $x-\delta<\xi<x+\delta\implies-\delta<\xi-x<\delta, \therefore
> > |\xi-x|<\delta$

Now, what I don't understand is, Courant's solution to part b of the problem. His solution is as follows:
\begin{align}
|F(x)-f(x)|\leq\frac{1}{2\delta}\int_{-\delta}^\delta|f(x+t)-f(x)|\,dt
\end{align}

I have tried to understand how he arrived at this conclusion, by trying to understand what the inequality actually means. I believe what the inequality means is:

> The distance between the average value of $f(t)$ in the interval $[x-\delta, x+\delta]$ & the value of $f(x)$ is lesser than or equal to the average distance between the points of the curve in the interval $[x-\delta, x+\delta]$ and the line $y=f(x)$.

I don't really know how to manipulate the expression $|F(x) - f(x)|$ to arrive at the conclusion Courant did. I would appreciate any advice or suggestions.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Use mathJax formatting for Mathematical expressions. For any assistance see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Hi David, welcome to MSE! Unfortunately, images cannot be searched, so it is important to have the problem typed in the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $f(x)=\frac{1}{2\delta} \int_{-\delta}^{\delta} f(x)\,dt$ for any $\delta$>0.

Comment: Short answer...

Comment: Any further help would make it fairly obvious.